# How to find the formulas for a "perfect-bell" curve between 0-1?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I would like to have a formula to generate the curves shown in the following plot:

[image]

The magnitude of curvature should be  adjusted by a parameter.
Does there exist any well-known function or distribution to define such curves?

Comment: The functions $1 - (1 - x)^p$ for $p \in [1, \infty)$ come to mind. Although, and I don't know if this is important to you, I don't think there's an axis of symmetry along the line $y = 1 - x$, which looks to be the case in your picture.

Comment: @TheoBendit Oh, it looks nice! Thanks a lot! Yes, I would indeed like to have a symmetric along $y = 1 - x$. When I try to increase $p$, it seems like that it saturates faster for the region $x\in[0.5, 1.0]$

Comment: Eric has just one-upped me. I think his answer is pretty much what you'd want. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $(1-(1-x)^p)^{1/p}$?  These are symmetric across the line $y = 1 - x$.

For $p=1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ (moving up and to the left as $p$ increases):
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Looks like [Theo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4277255/how-to-find-the-formulas-for-a-perfect-bell-curve-between-0-1/4277261#comment8901438_4277255) and I were thinking in similar directions.

Comment: ... but yours is better. (+1)

Comment: @EricTowers Wow, that's exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you very much :)

Comment: One more question, just being curious, did you construct this formula with some methods or a systematic way?

Comment: Can't speak for Eric, but one could arrive at this answer by being inspired by the [$p$-norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions). If you look at the $p$-norm balls illustrated to the right, you see roughly the "bell" shape that you're after. Eric's answer is the same shape, restricted and translated.

Comment: The $p = 4$ version has recently been called [squircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle), although I was familiar with the collection of these as "$p$-norm balls" before the term was coined.